# PostgreSQL is not creating any table while running springboot without any exception

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I cannot create any table or column in PostgreSQL with springboot and **there's no exception observed.** It's driving me crazy. I really need your help, here is my code:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "doctor_info")
public class DoctorInfo  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String fullName; 
    @Column
    private String department; 
    @Column
    private String userName; 
    @Column
    private String password;

}
```

This is application properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hospital
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
```

[this is the database I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mvqa.png)

Comment: 1) Best guess is whatever is doing creation process is not committing the transaction and all changes are lost when the session is closed. 2) To troubleshoot look at the Postgres log and see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: First, observe the queries that are executed where your database logs are logged. 
Second, change your `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`  to `create`.

At last, sometimes dropping the entire table that does not update the columns seems to be the only option. But make sure to do a pg_dump in case if you have important data in your database. 
I'd suggest trying this only on your local setup, because the implications are huge.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like Liquibase ( database schema change management)?
with that it's also easier to maintain your db.
For that you have to add the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and organize your db changes in changelog files, like described in here:
https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app

Answer (score 0):

I get your problem. You have to update your value at spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto inside application.properties.
There are 4 options are available for spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto as below

create | create-drop | update | validate | none

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

but you have to replace your parameter to **update** once your tables are created otherwise it will replace your table again.